# How to bind variable in string in SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, bind-variables

I am using SQL Developer. When I want to bind value. Normally I use following syntax:

```
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = :bindvalue
```

but, I don't know how to do that in string. The following query does not work.

```
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE column like '%:bindvalue%'
```

Why do I need it? Because my program runs a query in python and assigns something to bind variable:

```
    curr.execute('''SELECT * FROM table WHERE column''' = :bindvalue, bindvalue=somevalue)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Concatenate the prefix/suffix with the bind variable:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column like '%' || :bindvalue || '%'
```

Comment: In fact, it's so obvious that I'm ashamed. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Thanks for this, helped me today. Note for MySQL, you would need to use `CONCAT('%', :bindvalue, '%')` OR have the PIPES_AS_CONCAT SQL mode enabled.